# Get textbox value through button in popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I am a newbie to chrome-extension/java script development and I am stuck at the following exercise.

I created a popup with a button and a textbox. I wanted to pass the textbox value to an alert when the submit button is pressed. I have the following code so far:

**popup.html**

```
<div id="popup"></div>
<form name="q">
    <input name="query" id="userQuery" type="text" />
    <button id="button1">Submit</button>
    <!-- <input type="button" name="button" value="query" /> -->
</form>
```

**popup.js**

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    console.log(document.getElementById('userQuery'));
    document.getElementById('button1').addEventListener('click', myAlert(document.getElementById('userQuery')));
 });

function myAlert(query){
    alert(query.value)
}
```

However, I get "null" as query.value so the alert comes empty.
I also noticed that when the extension is clicked for the popup, I get an alert as well, which I don't understand why, I used both 'click' and 'onclick' but I get the same issue.

Any hint or help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it:

```
document.getElementById('button1').addEventListener('click', function() { myAlert(document.getElementById('userQuery')); });
```

In your code, the expression `myAlert(document.getElementById('userQuery'))` is evaluated when `addEventListener` is called. That's why you see a blank alert when the page loads. Instead you need to pass a function, that will be executed when the click event happens.

Comment: thank you! it solved both my issues. Solved it by sending in:

document.getElementById('button1').addEventListener('click', function() { myAlert(document.getElementById('userQuery').value); });

Answer (score 0):

Try this `$("#userQuery").val()` OR `document.getElementById("userQuery").value`

instead of     `document.getElementById('userQuery')`

Comment: Hi Ramesh, both the alternatives are providing me a blank as well